# Binomial law esperance to test null model of conductance

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, graph-theory

I am not a mathematician myself,and this question may sound too simple, but I couldn't find relevant answers with google or on this site. Also, I am not a native English speaker, so don't hesitate to point out incorrect grammar.

I have a simple elementary chain (in the graph theory sense). In each Node I have label. I want to know the mean of the probability (and/or the distribution) to have node with the same label that follow each other. This problem can be resumed to a list of $0$ and $1$. knowing the size of the list and the number of $1$, what is the probability to find some Label $1$ that is adjacent to an another Label $1$?

This is what I came up with (with the help of colleague) : $\mathrm{ E(B(n-1,  p^2))}$. Or the mean of binomial law with : $n$ size of list and $p$ the proportion of one.

I test it on an easy example, $n = 4$, $p = \frac{1}{2}$, with this formula we expect a mean of 0.75. However, if I draw it:

```
[1, 1, 0, 0]

[1, 0, 1, 0]

[1, 0, 0, 1]

[0, 1, 1, 0]

[0, 1, 0, 1]

[0, 0, 1, 1]
```

I found $\frac{3}{6} = 0.5$.

I am certainly missing something, but I can't figure out what.

Why I want to do that? Because I am bio-informatician and I found in environmental data some structure of node and I want to test it against a null model of randomness. So maybe I am completely wrong and I should just try to make thousand of simulation to approximate a random distribution?

Thanks for your time and help!

EDIT:  clarifying the question: I want to know the proportion of strings with adjacent 1s among the strings of length n with a fixed number m of 1s

Comment: how come you don't have [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], etc., in the list? is the label of each node 0 or 1 independently of other nodes? or do you want to know the proportion of strings with adjacent 1s among the strings of length n with a fixed number m of 1s ?

Comment: you are so right. I don't think about them because In my data I have a fixed number. But When it come to probability they take every case in account. you are rigth I have a fixed number of one I will edit the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are $\binom nm$ strings of length $n$ which contain $m$ $1$'s. Among them, there are $\binom {n+1-m}{m}$ strings in which two $1$'s are never adjacent, so the probability is $$1 - \frac{\binom{n+1-m}{m}}{\binom nm}$$ that there will be a pair of adjacent $1$'s.

To prove the formula $\binom{n+1-m}{m}$, we can take a string such as $1001$ with no two adjacent $1$'s, append a $0$ to the end (getting $10010$), and then divide it into blocks of $0$ and $10$: $(10, 0, 10)$ in this example. There are $n+1-m$ blocks, and $m$ of them are $10$, so there are $\binom{n+1-m}{m}$ ways to arrange them.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, the n + 1 trick is great.